# In r , library(mailR) always failed

Tags: r, email

When i run `library(mailR)`, the Rstudio always crashed . reinstalled the package can't solve it (library other package are no any issue) . Anyone can help?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is apparently a [known issue](https://github.com/rpremrajGit/mailR/issues/8), reported as early as April 29th.
However, the user reported that it worked calling `library(mailR)` from the console, indicating an issue with RStudio.

[A different user](https://github.com/rpremrajGit/mailR/issues/6#issuecomment-1031281953) noted that compiling `rJava` with a different version of `gcc` solved the issue.